# R display SQL last update on dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I'd like to have a line in my Flexdash that shows the last time my SQL script was read, thus displaying the last update date and time. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Did you look at _any_ R manual pages for functions that deal with file metadata? `?` / `help` usually has a _much faster_ execution response time than an SO round trip.

Comment: I did, but something like file.info("your_file")$mtime  may not tell me the last time the script itself was updated/last run.